# Overwriting a specific materialUI class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this theme in the project:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  ...defaultThemeConfig,
  overrides: {
    ...defaultThemeConfig.overrides,
    MuiListItem: {
      root: {
        '&:nth-child(odd)': {
          backgroundColor: colors.greyLight,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And I want to overwrite it in my styles.ts file like so:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(({ spacing, breakpoints, palette, zIndex }: Theme) => ({
  MuiListItem: {
    root: {
      '&:nth-child(odd)': {
        backgroundColor: 'none',
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

I also tried this:

```
'& MuiListItem': {
  root: {
    '&:nth-child(odd)': {
      backgroundColor: 'none',
    },
  },
},
```

I also tried this:

```
'.MuiListItem-root': {
  '&:nth-child(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
},
```

and this:

```
'& .MuiListItem-root': {
  '&:nth-child(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
},
```

and this:

```
'&.MuiListItem-root': {
  '&:nth-child(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
},
```

and so on.

But this ain't working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had another class, which I didn't know mattered, but here's the final solution:

```
mobileListItem: {
  '&:nth-child(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
  },
  cursor: 'pointer',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`makeStyles` modifies the class names to prevent conflicts with other class names.
Your overrides are probably getting renamed to `MuiListItem-root-123`. And that is why they're not being applied. You can try giving `!important`. Or you can use the following syntax to override classes:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => {
  listItemRoot: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
})

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return <ListItem classes={{ root: classes.listItemRoot }} />
}
```

Comment: My bad. The problem is I had to nest it into another class